# Cannot import Spring annotations,"web page cannot be displayed"

Tags: spring-boot, annotations

I am having a problem trying to add annotation @Service(and any other) to java class in SpringBoot;instead of usual appearance of popup with options to select annotation(e.g. import org.spring.service),i get one horizontaly divided popup and in bottom part it says `Attribute information for this '@Service' instance:Unspecified attributes:value`,and i am unable to add annotation..Also when I click on the click in up part of popup,it says "`web page cannot be displayed,most likely cause:some content or files on this webpage require a program that you don't have installed`".. Does anyone know the way how can i solve this?I checked if i have some dupplicate jars with different versions of spring boot,but i didn't found it..Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Eclipse Neon..it worked each time before when i worked with spring,i don't know why it won't now..